# modelling multiple changes in proportions beta glmm glmer

Tags: r, regression, beta, mixed-models

I have never done modelling this complicated before, so I would like to make sure I chose the most appropriate method.

I have data on the proportion of a particular Group of animals caught, out of the total animals caught at a location (a study). I would like to model whether the proportion of the animals in the Group (out of the total) changes over time for different size classes. I would like to include some random effects as well:

The random effects are:

- study ID (ID number)
- country (factor with several levels)

The fixed effects are:

- year (continuous variable)
- size class (factor with 3 levels small/medium/large)

Response variable, either:

- cbind(individualsGroup, total)
- proportion

Within each study i may have the proportion or small, medium and large individuals, if they were caught (from the same total number caught), but then I have many studies with different total numbers caught. Most of the response values are between 0 and 1, but a couple of the 385 data points are also 0 or 1 (i.e. no individuals or all individuals were small medium or large).

Originally i thought about modelling:

```
ger1 <- glmer(cbind(individualsGroup, total) ~ year*size + (1|studyID) + 
             (1|country), family = binomial, data = DF)
```

but with this I get convergence warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 2.85734 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

Then i read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233366/how-to-fit-binomial-glmm-with-continuous-response-between-0-and-1-that-is-not-a?rq=1) a response suggesting the use of glmmTMB, which I tried as follows:

```
tmb1<- glmmTMB(proportion ~ year*size + (1|studyID) + (1|country), DF, 
    family=list(family="beta",link="logit"))
```

With that model, I get the warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr) :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
2: In nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr) :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how I might resolve this, or to suggest alternative options?

Comment: any chance of a reproducible example?  I would *not* recommend switching to a Beta model, but you could try the binomial model in glmmTMB if you like (you need to specify the sample size via `weights=total`).  Have you tried rescaling/centering the `year` variable?

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. I tried using glmmTMB, with the weights = total, and with the centering of the year variable. However, it is not letting me fit a centered year^2 variable, and is giving me: Error in optimHess(par.fixed, obj$fn, obj$gr) : 
  gradient in optim evaluated to length 1 not 11
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr) :
  NA/NaN function evaluation